# Tailwind css has unexpected behavior using React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

So I have an array of colors

```js
 let colors=["red-500","blue-500","green-500","yellow-500","cyan-500","white-500","orange-500"]
```

and i wanna use a specific color depending on a number

```html
<h1 className={`bg-${colors[index]}`}></h1>
```

the colors are not always applied as intended for example sometimes it always be red or white
has anyone encountered similar issues with tailwind css + react ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tailwind will only build styles for classes that it detects in your code—but it does not actually run your source code and won’t detect dynamically constructed class names. Therefore, you must include the complete class name in your strings.

The styles that are working (like red and white) are probably included elsewhere in your code, and make it into the build, while the others are not.

**Don't construct class names dynamically**

```
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

**Always use complete class names**

```
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```

Source: [Dynamic class names - Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names=)

Answer (score 2):

While the answer from [@quartzic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72664420/541065) is a perfectly acceptable, I'd like to present an alternative.

The missing styles is most likely caused by Tailwind purging all styles that it doesn't detect being used anywhere in your code. This purge functionality can be configured by defining a safelist - a list of classes that shouldn't be purged under any circumstances.

In your case, I'd add the background color classes you want to use, to the safelist and you wont have to change anything in your React component. This is done in the `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  safelist: [
    'bg-red-500',
    'bg-blue-500',
    'bg-green-500',
    'bg-yellow-500',
    'bg-cyan-500',
  ]
  // ...
}
```

The downside is that it might increase your style bundle size, if your safelist includes classes that turned out to not be used anyways. In you case, this doesn't seem to be an issue though.

This safelist can even use regular expressions (although, I'd be vary of using that, as it might increase bundle size unexpectedly).

[You can read more in the Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)